# How to access Odoo11 web client HTML elements through my module to make some changes to them?

Tags: odoo-11

[image: Elements i need to access through odoo module]

As shown in the previous image i want to access the body and the sidebar elements of Odoo 11 web client to add a custom button inside the sidebar.

I want to access the sidebar element to add my button, and i want to access the body element to add a script with the method definition for my button to function.

I want to do this **through Odoo 11 module** and i want this button to be seen from any other installed module.

Knowing that **i am a pure beginner** in Odoo development so it is appreciated if you try to be as simple as you can.